How do I select multiple different counts with different where clauses in Google Sheets query language?
I'm currently trying to select multiple counts with different criteria. Unfortunately, I am getting a PARSE error when I try to combine them into the same query. They work fine individually, just not together. Anyone know how to fix this?
This works fine (separately)
Select count(Col2) where Col2 <= 180 

or 

Select count(Col2) where Col2 > 180

or

Select count(Col2)

This doesn't work (combined)
Select count(Col2) where Col2 <= 180, count(Col2) where Col2 > 180, count(Col2)

Error that I get when I try
Unable to parse query string for Function QUERY parameter 2: PARSE_ERROR: Encountered


you must use only one where
"select count(Col2) where Col2 <= 180 or Col2 > 180"

OR logic can be exchanged with AND logic if/when needed

try:
=INDEX(LET(a, A:B, {
 QUERY(a, "select count(Col2) where Col2 <= 180"), 
 QUERY(a, "select count(Col2) where Col2 > 180"), 
 QUERY(a, "select count(Col2)")}))


Possible to have multiple WHERE clauses in the same statement?  I need separate counts for statistical analysis.

@AlanSTACK only once per statement. see: https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/querylanguage#language-clauses

Ah, I was trying to avoid multiple statements because of the aforementioned network calls. Looks like that isn't possible. Oh well.
